# Office-js-helper

Tags: office-js, office-js-helpers

First, I am not a programmer, but a excel hobbyist on my journey from vba to office js add in to become a real software-maker. So maybe my question is stupid. I am building a office add with the set up:

- Visual Studio community 2017;
- Office 365 Enterprise E3 Developer;
- read the book Building Office Add-ins using Office.js (michael Zlatkovsky)
- used build in template for Office add in: Excel add in functionality;
- followed the steps to make the project typescript
- switched from fabric ui to bootstrap;

In script Lab are cool example code-snippets, which uses the office-js-helper library (github). For the question the part

```
async function createTable() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {

            await OfficeHelpers.ExcelUtilities.forceCreateSheet(context.workbook, "Indeling");
```

In the book also officehelper is mentioned, but not a descripton how to implement  it in the standard template of VS. It is a npm library. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/blob/master/README.md
I tried to reference the script in head of html but didn't get it right. 
I tried to add it by Quick install package (right-mouse-click in solution Explorer). Is there also a Nuget variant of this library? 
On a build a get the error  Build:Cannot find name 'OfficeHelpers'(TS2304).

How to get this right?

Edit

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<title>Grip op mijn Geld Develop</title>

<script src="office.helpers.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/office-js-helpers@1.0.2/dist/office.helpers.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/FabricUI/MessageBanner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- To enable offline debugging using a local reference to Office.js, use:                        -->
<!-- <script src="Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
<!-- <script src="Scripts/Office/1/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->

<link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Home.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/office-js-helpers@1.0.2/dist/office.helpers.min.js"></script>-->
<!-- For the Office UI Fabric, go to https://aka.ms/office-ui-fabric to learn more.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">-->
<!-- To enable the offline use of Office UI Fabric, use: -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/fabric.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/fabric.components.min.css">


<!-- For the Bootstrap UI -->
<link href="Content/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/OverrideCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And home.ts

```
declare var fabric: any;

(function () {
"use strict";

var cellToHighlight;
var messageBanner;

// The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded.
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialize the FabricUI notification mechanism and hide it
        var element = document.querySelector('.ms-MessageBanner');
        messageBanner = new fabric.MessageBanner(element);
        messageBanner.hideBanner();

        // If not using Excel 2016, use fallback logic.
        if (!Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.1)) {

            return;
        }

        // Attach button click event handlers
        $("#create-table").click(createTable);
        $("#create-table2").click(createTable);


        (window as any).Promise = OfficeExtension.Promise   

    });
};
async function createTable2() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {

            // await OfficeHelpers.ExcelUtilities.forceCreateSheet(context.workbook, "Indeling");

            await OfficeHelpers.ExcelUtilities.forceCreatesheet(context.workbook, "Sample");

            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("sample");

            const expenseTable = sheet.tables.add("A1:d1",true)

            expenseTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Type", "Soort", "Volgnr", "Hulp-Sorteer"]]

            expenseTable.rows.add(null /*add at the end*/, [
                ["1/1/2018", "the phone comp", "Communications", " €120"],
                ["1/5/2018", "the phone comp", "Anders", " €150"],
            ]);

            if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.2)) {
                sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
                sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
            }

            sheet.activate();

            await context.sync();


        });

    }
    catch (error) {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
        OfficeHelpers.Uilities.log(error);
    }



}




async function createTable() {
    try {
        await Excel.run(async (context) => {

            // await OfficeHelpers.ExcelUtilities.forceCreateSheet(context.workbook, "Indeling");

            let sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
            let sheetIndeling = sheets.add("Indeling");
            sheetIndeling.load("Indeling");

            // Create strings to store all static content to display in the Indeling sheet
            let sheetTitle = "Indeling";
            let sheetSubTitel1 = "Herkennen";
            let sheetSubTitel2 = "Categorieën";
            let sheetSubTitel3 = "Soort";
            let table1 = "HerkennenTable";
            let table2 = "CategorieTable";
            let table3 = "SoortTable";

            //Queue a command to fill white color in the sheet to remove gridlines
            sheetIndeling.getRange().format.fill.color = "white";

            // Add all static content to the Welcome sheet and format the text
            addContentToWorksheet(sheetIndeling, "B1:N1", sheetTitle, "SheetTitle");
            addContentToWorksheet(sheetIndeling, "B3:E3", sheetSubTitel1, "SheetSubTitle");
            addContentToWorksheet(sheetIndeling, "G3:I3", sheetSubTitel2, "SheetSubTitle");
            addContentToWorksheet(sheetIndeling, "K3:N3", sheetSubTitel3, "SheetSubTitle");
            addContentToWorksheet(sheetIndeling, "B5:E5", table1, "TableHeading");
            addContentToWorksheet(sheetIndeling, "G5:I5", table2, "TableHeading");
            addContentToWorksheet(sheetIndeling, "K5:N5", table3, "TableHeading");

            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Indeling");
            const herkennenTable = sheet.tables.add("B5:E5", true);
            const categorieTable = sheet.tables.add("G5:I5", true);
            const soortTable = sheet.tables.add("K5:N5", true);


            // Queue a command to set the header row
            herkennenTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Soort", "Categorie", "Herkennen-Kenmerk", "Nr"]];
            categorieTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Soort", "Categorie", "ID"]];
            soortTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [["Type","Soort","Volgnr","Hulp-Sorteer"]]

            herkennenTable.rows.add(null /*add at the end*/, [
                ["1/1/2018", "the phone comp", "Communications"," €120"],
                ["1/5/2018", "the phone comp", "Anders", " €150"],
            ]);

            if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.2)) {
                sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
                sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();
            }

            sheet.activate();

            await context.sync();


        });

    }
    catch (errorHandler) {

    }



}
// Helper function to add and format content in the workbook
function addContentToWorksheet(sheetObject, rangeAddress, displayText, typeOfText) {

    // Format differently by the type of content
    switch (typeOfText) {
        case "SheetTitle":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.values = displayText;
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 24;
            range.format.font.color = "yellow";
            range.merge();
            //Fill color in the brand bar
            sheetObject.getRange("A1:M1").format.fill.color = "#1f4e78";
            break;
        case "SheetSubTitle":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.values = displayText;
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 14;
            range.format.font.color = "#008000";
            range.format.fill.color = "yellow";
            range.format.horizontalAlignment = "center";
            range.merge();
            break;
        case "SheetHeading":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.values = displayText;
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 18;
            range.format.font.color = "#1f4e78";
            range.merge();
            break;
        case "SheetHeadingDesc":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.values = displayText;
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 10;
            range.merge();
            break;
        case "SummaryDataHeader":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.values = displayText;
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 13;
            range.merge();
            break;
        case "SummaryDataValue":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.numberFormat = "$#";
            range.values = displayText;
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 13;
            range.merge();
            break;
        case "TableHeading":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.values = displayText;
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 12;
            range.format.fill.color = "#1f4e78"
            range.format.font.color = "yellow";
            range.merge();
            break;
        case "TableHeaderRow":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 10;
            range.format.font.bold = true;
            range.format.font.color = "black";
            break;
        case "TableDataRows":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 10;
            sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress).format.borders.getItem('EdgeBottom').style = 'Continuous';
            sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress).format.borders.getItem('EdgeTop').style = 'Continuous';
            break;
        case "TableTotalsRow":
            var range = sheetObject.getRange(rangeAddress);
            range.format.font.name = "Corbel";
            range.format.font.size = 10;
            range.format.font.bold = true;
            break;
    }
}




// Helper function for treating errors
function errorHandler(error) {
    // Always be sure to catch any accumulated errors that bubble up from the Excel.run execution
    showNotification("Error", error);
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
}

// Helper function for displaying notifications
function showNotification(header, content) {
    $("#notification-header").text(header);
    $("#notification-body").text(content);
    messageBanner.showBanner();
    messageBanner.toggleExpansion();
}

})();
```

[Picture of project solution explore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTx2Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to reference the library, for testing, via `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/office-js-helpers@1.0.2/dist/office.helpers.min.js"></script>` in the HTML.  You can also copy that same file locally and use it from there.  Is that not working for you?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but i already thried the script reference in html (in head, different orders and under in the body html). Now i tried also to copy the code in a new file office.helpers.min.js in rootfolder (i think it is so called). It still isn't working.

Comment: I edit the question with the home.html and home.ts and a picture of the project solution explorer. Maybe you see directly the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I only stumbled on this now (was on vacation and missed the notification).  What the build system is complaining about is the lack of the definition files (which is what TypeScript needs), which are the "d.ts" files, not the js files.  As a short-term workaround, you can just do "declare var OfficeHelpers: any", but the long-term is to include the d.ts file that comes with the Office Js Helpers project into your project as well (i.e., if you're copying the JS file, copy the d.ts too -- unless you want to use NPM and webpack for both)

Comment: Hope you have had a nice holiday.Thank you, i appreciate you answered the question. I went for the short solution for now and it works. I am playing around to learn and make some "userforms" kind of interactions, i get messages like undefined alot, so i will make some time to learn more about typescript.